# Figure appears in next subsection

Tags: floats

```
\subsection{First} \index{First}

Some text of first subsection.

\begin{figure}[!htb] %[hbtp]
    \centering
        \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{images/a.pdf}}
    \caption{Some description}


    \label{a}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Second} \index{Second}

Some text
```

For some reason, the figure / image I want to implement appears in the second subsection, even though it's been declared at the end of the first subsection.

Other posts suggested using `[!htb]` which didn't help.

Thanks!

Comment: `[!htb]` makes it more likely that the figure floats further away as it prevents the figure being placed on a float page (no p)  but you can use the `placeins` package to stop floats going past a `\section`

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that I tried adding `\usepackage[section]{placeins}` to my main file, but that didn't have any affects on the figure.

Comment: that declaration will prevent the figure floating past a `\section` but if you have an error in your code you need to provide a complete document from `documentclass` to `\end{document}` so people can debug, (you can use `example-image` as the image as that is available for testing

Comment: note `[section]` stops floats going past `\section` but you show `\subsection` so you would need `\FloatBarrier` (or simply `\clearpage`) before the `\subsection`